# Checking for null and empty values in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this if statement? If i pass not empty values i still don't get in to the if block

Both `val1` and `val2` have values:

```js
let val1 = 'category'
let val2 = 'medical'

if ((val1 !== null || val1 !== '') && (val2 !== null || val2 !== '')) {

  console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

`val1` is empty and `val2` has a value:

```js
let val1 = ''
let val2 = 'medical'

if ((val1 !== null || val1 !== '') && (val2 !== null || val2 !== '')) {

  console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

Comment: The `||`'s should be `&&`'s

Comment: Using what sample of input for `[val1, val2]` do you expect it to enter the `if`. Because actually, for `val1="foo", val2="bar"` I'm getting the console output.

Comment: val1 is 'category' and val2 is 'medical' , the expected result should be 'category medical'

Comment: Your condition will always be `true` because you can't have a variable that is an empty string and `null` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `&&` and not `||`, because what you are currently saying is:

> `Val` cannot be `null` or it cannot be `empty`.

As long as one of those evaluates to `true`, it will enter the `if statement`. Since an `empty string` does not equal `null`, the `null` check is `true` which means one of the checks evaluated to `true` and would enter the `if statement`. If it was vise versa, then the `empty string` would evaluate to `true` and again it would enter the `if statement`.

This would make more sense if you were checking for equality and would then read as follows:

> `Val` can be `null` or it can be `empty`.

However, that isn't what you are looking for, so what you want to say is:

> `Val` cannot be `null` **AND** it cannot be `empty`.

- When testing a single variable to **not equal** multiple values use an `&&` check.
- When testing a single variable to **equal** one of multiple values use an `||` check.

```js
let val1 = 'category'
let val2 = 'medical'

if ((val1 !== null && val1 !== '') && (val2 !== null && val2 !== '')) {
  console.log(val1, val2);
}

val1 = ''

if ((val1 !== null && val1 !== '') && (val2 !== null && val2 !== '')) {
  console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition `val1 !== null || val1 !== ''` or `val2 !== null && val2 !== ''` will always be `true`

Its saying is `val1` is not equal to `null` or empty string. Consider if its `null` the other part will be automatically `true` and vice versa.

You should use `&&` instead of `||`

```js
var val1 = 'a'
var val2 = ''
if((val1 !== null && val1 !== '') && (val2 !== null && val2 !== '')){
    console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

A clean code can a be achieved using `every()` and `includes()`

```js
var val1 = 'a'
var val2 = ''
if([val1, val2].every(x => ![null,''].includes(x))){
    console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the || to && in your if statement.

```js
let val1 = 'category'
let val2 = 'medical'

if ((val1 !== null && val1 !== '') && (val2 !== null && val2 !== '')) {

  console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

```js
let val1 = ''
let val2 = 'medical'

if ((val1 !== null && val1 !== '') && (val2 !== null && val2 !== '')) {

  console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks forks , i changed || to && it now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, this sort of expression `(val1 !== null || val1 !== '')` needs to be changed to `(val1 !== null && val1 !== '')`, otherwise the condition will be `true` for `val1 = null` or `val1 = ''`, example:

- Assume `val1 = null`, then `(val1 !== null || val1 !== '')` will be evaluated to `(null !== null || null !== '')` and this will result in `(false || true)` that equals `true`.

Now, for your particular case, you can create a method that returns `true` when you consider a variable is `"defined"` (you may check for `undefined` also) and do something like this:

```js
function _isDefined(val)
{
    return ![null, undefined, ""].includes(val);
}

let tests = [
  ["category", "medical"],
  ["category", null],
  [undefined, "medical"],
  ["", null],
  ["something", ""]
];

tests.forEach(function(test)
{
    let [val1, val2] = test;

    if (_isDefined(val1) && _isDefined(val2))
        console.log(val1, val2);
});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just say `if`. For example:

```js
var x = "";
var y = null;
var z;
var argArray = [x,y,z];

function hasValue(arg){
  if(arg){
    console.log("arg has some value"); 
  } else {
    console.log("arg has no value and is " + arg); 
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < argArray.length; i++) {
  hasValue(argArray[i]);
}
```